# How to Loop cut multiple selected edges at once

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am coming from Modo. And in Modo I could select multiple edges and cut loop of them at ones. What I mean, for example, is if I have a cylinder with 32 faces and I need to add an edge loop to every face,  I select top edge loop, press <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and it cuts every single edge of that loop.

But in Blender when I chose edge loop and press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> it only cuts which edge my cursor is on. So, do I need manually add edge loop to every edge one by one?

I found only one tip for that problem, select face loop, insert it but it works on simple geometry but for complex shape it doesn't work perfect.

Comment: @Duarte:  in my opinion questions which were asked for newer version of blender (which looks totally different for beginners (and me) should not be closed with answers of older blender versions....

Comment: Actually that already answered thing is not an actual answer for that question :D Not even relevant. Dont know how to delete that thing. It will mislead people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking at the subdivide operation.

[image]

Here, in edge mode, I've selected two edge rings (ctrl alt RMB on edge, then shift ctrl alt RMB on edge, at least for me; interfaces may vary depending on startup interface choices) on the left, and then used a subdivide operation.  I accessed the subdivide via the context menu ('w' key for me) followed by selecting subdivision ('s').

We can see that it made a loop cut through both of the edge rings that I selected.

Comment: Oh, Wow. It is 99.9 percent what I want. It even enables some fancy posibilities. )) 

So, first thing first, for this to work, I need to select all edge loops where I want new loop cut will go. But with like you said, via edge ring and select->edge Loops->edgeLoop menu, this will work. 

With Ctrl+E and subdivide Edge-Ring function, it even makes smooth loops and keeps curvatures with blend surface interpolation choice. For some reason it doesnt work pecfect with subdivide :/

The only problem, I cant slide new loop same as loop cut tool. But technically, I can with extra steps